# nginx custom 404 error page does not return when with wrong links ending with ".html"

Tags: php, html, nginx

I have a custom 404 page which returns correctly when a non existing address is queried, e.g. "www.example.com/test/testjihi" will return my custom 404 page correctly.

However IF the non existing address is specified with a .html extension, like: "www.example.com/test/testjihi.html" then a default "file not found" page is returned instead of the custom 404 page.

I configure the error page globally:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /www;
    error_page   404 /404.html; # this is my custom page
    ...
```

Any idea?

Apologies for the poor terminology ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can use the error_page property in the nginx config.
Check out this link: http://expressica.com/2008/03/22/nginx-set-up-error-pages/

Comment: Fixed it, thanks to one of the comments in your link.

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;

Comment: Okay I'm glad you got it to work! I didn't see your example code when I first read your post :p